# How to JSON_REPLACE value with an object (["Ra"]) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

How to replace JSON Object value with an object?

If the earlier value is an integer. `{"data":12345}` and I want to replace with

```
{"data":["12345"]}
```

I tried:

```
JSON_REPLACE(data, '$.data', ['12345'])  //SQL Syntax Error
JSON_REPLACE(data, '$.data', "['12345']")  //Output: {"data": "['12345']"} (wrong)
```

Comment: The second one produces what I thought you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked using following:

```
JSON_REPLACE(data, '$.data', JSON_ARRAY('12345')))
```